# Batch rename refactoring

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Is it possible to search and replace all class names inside a folder to apply a prefix, and at the same time automatically refactor the usages to use the new name and also update the file names according to the new class names?

I know how to do this for each individual class but I have a folder with a lot of files so wonder if there is some automatic way.

E.g. in my folder I have

```
Class1.cs
Class2.cs
```

with contents respectively

```
public class Class1 {public Class2 Prop {get;}}
public class Class2 {public Class1 Prop {get;}}
```

And I want to add a prefix, 'My' to all the classes such that the above will look like this after the operation:

```
MyClass1.cs
MyClass2.cs
```

with contents respectively

```
public class MyClass1 {public MyClass2 Prop {get;}}
public class MyClass2 {public MyClass1 Prop {get;}}
```

Comment: intellij has something called structrual search and replace which might be close to what you wnat. But I did not find anything similar with Resharper. Not sure Resharper has extensions that can do that.

Comment: You can do it for Class1 and then Class2, but not both at the same time I think. Refactor > Rename